# How to merge multiple columns into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with ~1M rows and around 20 columns. I'm looking to merge these columns into one; under the same unique identifier column.

To illustrate, this is the raw data:

```
          ID   Column 2 Column 3
0       1001          B        A
1       1002          C        D
2       1003          E        E
3       1004          G        H
```

Desired outcome:

```
          ID     Merged
0       1001          B
1       1001          A
2       1002          C
3       1002          D
4       1003          E
5       1003          E
6       1004          G
7       1004          H
```

Since there are ~20 columns I'm looking to merge; I need to merge them through a loop. I used the below code but I always get a memory error.

```
master = pd.DataFrame()
for col in original_df:  # original_df is the dataframe combining the 20 columns
    if col != 'ID':
        temp = pd.DataFrame()
        temp['ID'] = original_df['ID']
        temp['Merged'] = original_df[col]
        master = master.append([temp])
```

Comment: This is not really a duplicate question.  The OP wants a repeated "ID" value even if the "Merged" values are identical for the same "ID" value.  The other question does not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `df.melt`, something like this:

```
newdf = (df.melt(id_vars='ID', value_vars = ['Column 2', 'Column 3'],
                 value_name='Merged')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .sort_values('ID'))

>>> newdf
     ID Merged
0  1001      B
4  1001      A
1  1002      C
5  1002      D
2  1003      E
6  1003      E
3  1004      G
7  1004      H
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
In [43]: df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('Merged').reset_index()

Out[43]: 
     ID Merged
0  1001      B
1  1001      A
2  1002      C
3  1002      D
4  1003      E
5  1003      E
6  1004      G
7  1004      H
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an efficient way using `numpy`.

**Given two columns**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

res = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.repeat(df['ID'], 2),
                    'Data': np.hstack((df['Column 2'], df['Column 3']))})

print(res)

  Data    ID
0    B  1001
0    C  1001
1    E  1002
1    G  1002
2    A  1003
2    D  1003
3    E  1004
3    H  1004
```

**Given arbitrary number of columns**

You can use a list comprehension with `numpy.hstack`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.repeat(df['ID'], len(df.columns[1:])),
                    'Data': np.hstack([df[col] for col in df.columns[1:]])})
```

Answer (score 2):

With a comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([[i, v] for i, *V in df.values for v in V], columns=['ID', 'Merged'])

     ID Merged
0  1001      B
1  1001      A
2  1002      C
3  1002      D
4  1003      E
5  1003      E
6  1004      G
7  1004      H
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index().drop(['level_1'], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Merged'})

ID  Merged
0   1001    B
1   1001    A
2   1002    C
3   1002    D
4   1003    E
5   1003    E
6   1004    G
7   1004    H
```